# Dir.glob to get all csv and xls files in folder

Tags: ruby, arrays, yield, dir

```
folder_to_analyze = ARGV.first
folder_path = File.join(Dir.pwd, folder_to_analyze)

unless File.directory?(folder_path)
  puts "Error: #{folder_path} no es un folder valido."
  exit
end

def get_csv_file_paths(path)
  files = []
  Dir.glob(path + '/**/*.csv').each do |f|
    files << f
  end
  return files
end

def get_xlsx_file_path(path)
  files = []
  Dir.glob(path + '/**/*.xls').each do |f|
    files << f
  end
  return files
end

files_to_process = []
files_to_process << get_csv_file_paths(folder_path)
files_to_process << get_xlsx_file_path(folder_path)
puts files_to_process[1].length # Not what I want, I want:
# puts files_to_process.length
```

I'm trying to make a simple script in Ruby that allows me to call it from the command line, like `ruby counter.rb mailing_list1` and it goes to the folder and counts all .csv and .xls files.

I intend to operate on each file, getting a row count, etc.

Currently the `files_to_process` array is actually an array of array - I don't want that. I want to have a single array of both .csv and .xls files.

Since I don't know how to yield from the `Dir.glob` call, I added them to an array and returned that.

How can I accomplish this using a single array?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Well, yielding is simple. Just `yield`.

```
def get_csv_file_paths(path)
  Dir.glob(path + '/**/*.csv').each do |f|
    yield f
  end
end

def get_xlsx_file_path(path)
  Dir.glob(path + '/**/*.xls').each do |f|
    yield f
  end
end

files_to_process = []
get_csv_file_paths(folder_path) {|f| files_to_process << f }
get_xlsx_file_path(folder_path) {|f| files_to_process << f }

puts files_to_process.length
```

Every method in ruby can be passed a block. And `yield` keyword sends data to that block. If the block may or may not be provided, `yield` is usually used with `block_given?`.

```
yield f if block_given?
```

### Update

The code can be further simplified by passing your block directly to `glob.each`:

```
def get_csv_file_paths(path, &block)
  Dir.glob(path + '/**/*.txt').each(&block)
end

def get_xlsx_file_path(path, &block)
  Dir.glob(path + '/**/*.xls').each(&block)
end
```

Although this block/proc conversion is a little bit of advanced topic.

Comment: @Merovex: note, however, that this post answers what I thought is the direct question ("how do I yield from this?"), rather than gift-wrapping a complete solution.

Comment: Fair enough, though the "yield" part of the request is buried down in the narrative. Might have helped to mention that in the base question. ;-)

Answer (score 52):

Just stick the file extensions together into one group:

```
Dir[path + "/**/*.{csv,xls}"]
```

Comment: IMO, this is a more rubyist answer. It's one line and legible. Though, I would have done:

Dir["#{path}/**/*.{csv,xls}]

clearly six of one and a half dozen of the other.

Answer (score 2):

```
def get_folder_paths(root_path)
  Dir.glob('**/*.csv') + Dir.glob('**/*.xls')
end

folder_path = File.join(Dir.pwd, ARGV.first || '')
raise "#{folder_path} is not a valid folder" unless File.directory?(folder_path)

puts get_folder_paths(folder_path).length
```

The `get_folder_paths` method returns an array of CSV and XLS files.  Building an array of file names may not be what you really want, especially if there are a *lot* of them.  An approach using the Enumerator returned by Dir.glob would be more appropriate in that case if you did not need the file count first.